# run a Job when device is charging using android JobScheduler

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

we can't use manifest broadcast receiver to detect if the device is charging. can we use jobscheduler to detect if the device is charging ? i.e if the device is plugged in start my activity.. any example?

Comment: You cannot start activities from the background on modern versions of Android.

Comment: even for the [implicit broadcasts?] (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions)